# How can I split up a string into two doubles using a tempArray?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chpt4_Project {

    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the first city: ");
        // Prompt user for city
        String city1 = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter the second city: ");
        // Prompt user for the second city
        String city2 = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter the latitude and longitude of the first city separated by a space (Ex. 28.8 81.2): ");
        String coord1 = input.toString();
        // Save coordinates as a string
        String [] tempArray1 = coord1.substring(coord1.indexOf("(")+1, coord1.lastIndexOf(")")).split(" ");
        // Split string
        double lat1 = Double.parseDouble(tempArray1[0]);
        double long1 = Double.parseDouble(tempArray1[1]);


        System.out.print("Enter the latitude and longitude of the second city separated by a space (Ex. 28.8 81.2): ");
        String coord2 = input.toString();
        // Save coordinates as a string
        String [] tempArray2 = coord2.substring(coord2.indexOf("(")+1, coord2.lastIndexOf(")")).split(" ");
        // Split string
        double lat2 = Double.parseDouble(tempArray2[0]);
        double long2 = Double.parseDouble(tempArray2[1]);

        double x = (long1 - long2) * 55;
        double y = (lat1 - lat2) * 69;
        double distance = Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y);

        System.out.println("The distance between " + city1 + city2 + " is " + distance + "miles.");
    }

}
```

Introductory coding student, I'm trying to make a program that will tell me the distance between two city coordinates.But, when I try to split the string the longitude and latitude are on I can't seem to get the `tempArrays` right.

Here are the results, thanks in advance!

```
"Enter the first city: 
Enter the second city: 
Enter the latitude and longitude of the first city separated by a space (Ex. 28.8 81.2): Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at Chpt4_Project.main(Chpt4_Project.java:22)
"
```

Comment: There's no JavaScript in code. please use relevant tag

Comment: Noted and fixed.

Comment: I am trying to teach you how to find bugs: use a debugger or some test output to check how your `coord1` string actually looks like before you process it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved Try To Run Below Code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main{
private static Scanner input;
     public static void main(String []args){

         input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the first city: ");
    // Prompt user for city
    String city1 = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the second city: ");
    // Prompt user for the second city
    String city2 = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the latitude and longitude of the first city separated by a space (Ex. 28.8 81.2): ");
    String coord1 = input.nextLine();
    // Save coordinates as a string
    String [] tempArray1 = coord1.split(" ");
    // Split string
    double lat1 = Double.parseDouble(tempArray1[0]);
    double long1 = Double.parseDouble(tempArray1[1]);


    System.out.print("Enter the latitude and longitude of the second city separated by a space (Ex. 28.8 81.2): ");
    String coord2 = input.nextLine();
    // Save coordinates as a string
    String [] tempArray2 = coord2.split(" ");
    // Split string
    double lat2 = Double.parseDouble(tempArray2[0]);
    double long2 = Double.parseDouble(tempArray2[1]);

    double x = (long1 - long2) * 55;
    double y = (lat1 - lat2) * 69;
    double distance = Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y);

    System.out.println("The distance between " + city1 + city2 + " is " + distance + "miles.");




     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're not reading new input when asking for the latitude and longitude. You're actually converting the `Scanner` object to a string and then trying to parse it, which is clearly not your objective. Simply read new input from the user as follows:

```
System.out.print("Enter the latitude and longitude of the first city separated by a space (Ex. 28.8 81.2): ");
String coord1 = input.toString(); //Needs to be replaced
```

The second line should be replaced with `input.nextLine();`

The same goes for the second chunk of code that asks for latitude and longitude.